# Making sublist indices refer to the original list

Tags: python

I need to check some sublist for a particular property, and then return the bin which satisfies that property, but as an index of the original list. Currently I'm having to do this manually:

```
sublist = mylist[start:end]

positive = search(sublist)
positive = start + positive 
posiveList.append(positive)
```

Is there a more elegant/idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a better example to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking is this:

> If I search and find an index in a sublist, is there a straightforward way to convert it to its index in the original list?

No, the only way is what you're already doing: you need to add the `start` offset back to the index to get the index in the original list.

This makes sense because there is *no actual association* between the sublist and the original list. Take this example for instance:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = x[1:3]
>>> z = [2,3]
>>> y == z
True
```

`z` has just as much of a relationship to `x` as `y` has to `x`. Even though `y` was created using slicing syntax, it's just a copy of a range of elements in `x`—it is just a vanilla list and has no actual references to the original list `x`. Since there is no relationship between `x` and `y` built into `y`, there's no way to get the original `x`-index back from a `y`-index.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to save indexes of all matching element.

If so, then think you are looking for this:

```
positiveList = [i for i, item in enumerate(mylist[start:end])
                if validate_item(item)]
```

Where `validate_item` should essentially check whether this item is required or not and return True/False.

Answer (score 0):

If your search operator supports it or can be modified to support it then `search(wholelist, startfrom, endat)` should return the actual index.